# tmux can not be started in terminal as normal user but as root?

Tags: x11, tmux, archlinux, xfce

I use Archlinux 32-bit on an old Lenovo X60 Thinkpad. It works great but I have a problem with tmux: Whenever I try to launch tmux as a normal user in st-terminal or in xfce4-terminal (or I guess in other terminal emulators too) I get the following error:

> setterm: terminal screen does not support --blength
>
> /usr/lib/xorg-server/Xorg.wrap: Only console users are allowed to run the X server

After that message there is no way to input any commands and a few seconds later tmux stops. I use tmux inside a terminal emulator that is launched in i3wm inside an xserver.

The strange thing is that if I start tmux as root user (sudo tmux) I only get the setterm-error but after that I can use tmux as normal. So I guess that something in my xorg config is damaged but I can't figure out what. So does anyone has an idea?

Comment: [first google result](https://github.com/sofar/xorg-launch-helper/issues/7)

Comment: that doesn't help... instead of just tmux, my whole virtual terminal crashes